# Living vs Staying

Tags: word-usage

1. A few years back, I was living in a student dormitory.
2. A few years back, I was staying in a student dormitory.

Which one of the above is correct and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, although 'staying' conveys the additional information that you were living in the dormitory temporarily.

> live verb (HAVE A HOME)
> live in, at, etc.
> to have your home
> somewhere
>
> stay verb (LIVE)
> to live or be in a place for a short time
> as a visitor

[Live (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/live)

[Stay (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/staying)

Comment: There may be regional differences at play here. This is not a good answer for Am.E. (the author is a Br.E speaker).

Comment: Another regional difference— in Scotland it's very very common to hear "stay" for your permanent residence, although it isn't standard British England.

Answer (score -1):

When I'm on vacation, I often **stay** in a hotel. But I've never lived in a hotel. Sometimes, friends or relatives who **live** far away come and **stay** at my house for a few days.

So which is correct for your particular situation? Maybe either could work?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's simply not true, at least in Am.E: staying **does not** imply living. I'd describe it the other way around: living implies staying somewhere and adds more permanent intent.

Comment: I don't see any transatlantic difference between these two answers. As a British English speaker like @MichaelHarvey, I wouldn't speak of 'living in a hotel' unless it was a semi-permanent arrangement, not a two-week holiday..

Comment: @KateBunting I agree with that, and I wasn't previously aware of any transatlantic differences either. The comment I was replying to has now been deleted (but the downvote hasn't been retracted) so I'm not sure what to think. But as I recall, it was suggesting the opposite: that "living somewhere" was consistent with short-term stays like in a hotel.